# What does freq='infer' do in pandas shift? How does it differ from freq='D'?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I didn't see the difference between freq in [`.shift()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html)

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Col1": [10, 20, 15, 30, 45],
                   "Col2": [13, 23, 18, 33, 48],
                   "Col3": [17, 27, 22, 37, 52]},
                  index=pd.date_range("2020-01-01", "2020-01-05"))

df.shift(periods=2, freq="infer")

            Col1  Col2  Col3
2020-01-03    10    13    17
2020-01-04    20    23    27
2020-01-05    15    18    22
2020-01-06    30    33    37
2020-01-07    45    48    52
```

return the same as

```
df.shift(periods=2, freq="d")

            Col1  Col2  Col3
2020-01-03    10    13    17
2020-01-04    20    23    27
2020-01-05    15    18    22
2020-01-06    30    33    37
2020-01-07    45    48    52
```

Can someone explain what the `freq='infer'` parameter does?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`freq='infer'` means that the frequency is inferred from the index metadata.

> **freq** DateOffset, tseries.offsets, timedelta, or str, optional
>
> Offset to use from the tseries module or time rule (e.g. ‘EOM’).
>
> If freq is specified then the index values are shifted but the data is
> not realigned. That is, use freq if you would like to extend the index
> when shifting and preserve the original data. **If freq is specified as
> “infer” then it will be inferred from the freq or inferred_freq
> attributes of the index. If neither of those attributes exist, a
> ValueError is thrown.**

Assuming this example with an Index that has a frequency of 2 weeks:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Col1": [10, 20, 15, 30, 45],
                   "Col2": [13, 23, 18, 33, 48],
                   "Col3": [17, 27, 22, 37, 52]},
                  index=pd.date_range("2020-01-01", periods=5, freq='2W'))

df.index
# DatetimeIndex(['2020-01-05', ..., '2020-03-01'], dtype='datetime64[ns]',
#               freq='2W-SUN')  # <- the important part
```

`df.shift(periods=2, freq='infer')` will shift 2 periods of 2W = 4 weeks:

```
df.shift(periods=2, freq='infer')
            Col1  Col2  Col3
2020-02-02    10    13    17   # 4W after 2020-01-05
2020-02-16    20    23    27
2020-03-01    15    18    22
2020-03-15    30    33    37
2020-03-29    45    48    52   # 4W after 2020-03-01
```

In comparison a simple `df.shift(periods=2)` just shifts by 2 rows:

```
df.shift(periods=2)

            Col1  Col2  Col3
2020-01-05   NaN   NaN   NaN
2020-01-19   NaN   NaN   NaN
2020-02-02  10.0  13.0  17.0
2020-02-16  20.0  23.0  27.0
2020-03-01  15.0  18.0  22.0
```

In your example, the default frequency of `date_range` is `D`, so this indeed gives the same output. Let's change it to `freq='3D'`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Col1": [10, 20, 15, 30, 45],
                   "Col2": [13, 23, 18, 33, 48],
                   "Col3": [17, 27, 22, 37, 52]},
                  index=pd.date_range("2020-01-01", periods=5, freq='3D'))

# shift by 2 * D
df.shift(periods=2, freq='D')
            Col1  Col2  Col3
2020-01-03    10    13    17  # 2*1D after 2020-01-01
2020-01-05    20    23    27
2020-01-07    15    18    22
2020-01-09    30    33    37
2020-01-11    45    48    52

# shift by 2 * 3D = 6D
df.shift(periods=2, freq='infer')
            Col1  Col2  Col3
2020-01-07    10    13    17  # 2*3D after 2020-01-01
2020-01-10    20    23    27
2020-01-13    15    18    22
2020-01-16    30    33    37
2020-01-19    45    48    52
```

Comment: freq = 'infer' everytime multiply on 2?

Comment: @LeaForaSFora we multiply the inferred frequency by `periods`. If you have `periods=3, freq='infer'` and your index freq is `4D` you will shift by `3*4D = 12D`

Comment: I updated the last example for clarity

Comment: df.shift(periods=3, freq='D') gives another result, you need to correct this

Comment: I saw it as well and just changed it, thanks for the heads up ;)